# SOME/IP length error in trace window when sending SOME/IP messages from CANOE using CAPL script

Tags: networking

I am getting SOME/IP length error(but getting correct data) in trace window when sending SOME/IP messages from CANOE using CAPL script. I think i am missing any settings that should be done in Canoe.

Can anyone suggest a possible reason for this? and how to solve this? The code used to send SOME/IP message is given below..

Any help is highly appreciated...

```
on key 'w'  
{  
  DWORD messageId = 0x12340004; // service ID = 0x1234, method ID = 0x0004  
  DWORD requestId = 0; // client ID = 0, session ID = 0  
  DWORD protocolVersion = 1;  
  DWORD interfaceVersion = 1;  
  DWORD messageType = 0x2; // notification message  
  DWORD returnCode = 0; // not available  
  DWORD aep = 0; // application endpoint handle  
  DWORD messageHandle = 0; // handle of the created SOME/IP message  
  BYTE payload[5]; // the message payload  
  DWORD count = 0; // a simple counter  

  // initialize the payload  
  count = 0;  
  payload[count++] = 0x11;  
  payload[count++] = 0x22;  
  payload[count++] = 0x33;  
  payload[count++] = 0x44;  
  payload[count++] = 0x55;  

  // open application endpoint  
  aep = SomeIpOpenLocalApplicationEndpoint(17, 50002);  

  // create the SOME/IP message itself and set the message payload  
  messageHandle = SomeIpCreateMessage(messageId,requestId,protocolVersion,interfaceVersion,messagType,returnCode);  
  SomeIpSetData(messageHandle,elcount(payload),payload);  

  // send the SOME/IP message  
  SomeIpOutputMessage(aep,0xFFFFFFFF,40001,messageHandle);  

  // release the some IP message  
  SomeIpReleaseMessage(messageHandle);  
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are running, or the output?

Comment: This is the CAPL script to send SOME/IP message from Canoe

Comment: Then please provide the entire error message, as well as additional context regarding what it is you are developing and/or testing in CANoe.